# How to get first n characters from a string in R

Tags: r, string, tidyverse

I would like to extract three letters of each string for each row in `df` as below

Exampe:

```
df <- data.frame(name = c('Jame Bond', "Maria Taylor", "Micheal Balack"))
df
            name
1      Jame Bond
2   Maria Taylor
3 Micheal Balack
```

desired out

```
df_new 
        name
1      Jam_Bon
2      Mar_Tay
3      Mic_Bal
```

Any sugesstions for this using tidyverse?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```r
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)

df$name %>% 
  str_extract_all("(?<=(^|[:space:]))[:alpha:]{3}") %>% 
  map_chr(~ str_c(.x, collapse = "_"))
```

The `stringr` cheatsheet is very useful for working through these types of problems.
https://www.rstudio.com/resources/cheatsheets/

<sup>Created on 2022-03-26 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 4):

You can try this with `dplyr::rowwise()`, `stringr::str_split()` and `stringr::str_sub()`:

```
df_new <- df %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(name = paste(
    unlist(
      lapply(str_split(name, ' '), function(x){
        str_sub(x, 1, 3)
      })
    ), 
    collapse = "_"
  ))
```

I got the same result as you expected :

```
> df_new
# A tibble: 3 x 1
# Rowwise: 
  name   
  <chr>  
1 Jam_Bon
2 Mar_Tay
3 Mic_Bal
```

Answer (score 2):

An alternative method using `tidyr` functions:

```
df |> 
  extract(name, c("x1","x2"), "(\\w{3}).*\\s(\\w{3})") |> 
  unite(col = "name",x1,x2, sep = "_")
```

Giving:

```
     name
1 Jam_Bon
2 Mar_Tay
3 Mic_Bal
```

Note that this assumes all first names and surnames have at least 3 characters, otherwise replace the extract regex with `"(\\w{1,3}).*\\s(\\w{1,3})"`

Answer (score 1):

In `base R`, we can use `sub` - capture (`(...)`) the first three non-space (`\\S`) characters from the start (`^`), followed by zero or more non-white space and a white space (`\\S*\\s`), then capture the second set of 3 non-white characters.  In the replacement, specify the backreferences (`\\1`, `\\2`) of the captured groups and insert underscore (`_`) between those

```
df$name <- sub("^(\\S{3})\\S*\\s(\\S{3}).*", "\\1_\\2", df$name)
df$name
[1] "Jam_Bon" "Mar_Tay" "Mic_Bal"
```

Comment: Thank you @akrun.... Long time to ask you again :D